# Retrieve post taxonomy inside get_posts()

Tags: php, html, wordpress, foreach

I am retrieving posts from my Custom Post Type using the built-in Wordpress `get_posts()` function.  I am able to print/retrieve all of the data for the post except the post's taxonomy term (which I registered as a custom taxonomy using `register_taxonomy( 'developer_category', 'developer', $args );` Here's my code for displaying the posts...

```
<?php $devs = get_posts([
    'post_type'     => 'developer',
    'posts_per_page'    => '8',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
]); ?>

<div id="loaded-devs">
    <?php $post_count = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($devs as $dev): ?>
        <div class="loaded-dev" id="dev<?php echo $post_count; ?>"> 
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $dev->ID, 'small' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($dev); ?>" class="full-link"></a>
            <h2><?php echo $dev->post_title; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo get_the_terms($dev->ID); ?> Developer</p>
        </div>
        <?php $post_count ++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Using get_cat_name as I am above returns 'Uncategorized', I believe because it's looking for the default Wordpress category and I am categorizing by custom taxonomy.  How can I display my post's taxonomy name inside `get_posts()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the taxonomy to `get_the_terms()`:

```
$my_tax_terms = get_the_terms( $dev->ID, 'developer_category' );
```

This returns an array of terms that you can then loop through. Also, you can't just `echo` it because it's an array. You can `print_r( $my_tax_terms )` to see what you get, but you'll need to loop through the results to pull the information you want.